# Best practice for combining two lists

Tags: list, list-view

I know it's a common SharePoint problem. I want to accumulate two SharePoint lists on MOSS 2007. One is a calendar list and the second a custom list with a date column. I want both in another list. The only function the target list must have is to show the items of both lists. There mustn't be a function for creating new items on this list. The view should be near realtime.

What should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access to Sharepoint Designer then a Dataview Webpart will do this nicely. You can convert it to xsl and ensure there are no options to edit the items. There are plenty of examples of creating these on the net. I recommend looking for examples from Laura Rogers.

Comment: This would definately be the easiest option. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101154041033.aspx

Comment: Agreed - A merged data source with a DVWP is the solution here.

Answer (score 2):

If you customize anything in SharePoint Designer, remember, that it will break the attachments toolbar.

Comment: Certainly this is true if this was a custom form. In this case it is just a view and should not be affected.